# Phase velocity higher than the light speed for high frequencies in glass

Tags: waves, refraction, frequency, glass, phase-velocity

The phase velocity is higher than the light speed for very high frequencies in glass, but nothing should transmit information faster than the light in the vacuum. So I read that a pure sinusoid wave that moves at the phase speed can't transmit information since that wave covers an infinite domain, thus that wave has always be there and will always be there. That kind of wave is form with an infinity waves of different frequencies. The signals are then transmited by "blocks".

My questions are:
What's a pure sinusoid wave?

I'm not sure to understand why that kind of wave covers an infinite domain.

Are the "blocks" of wave moves at the group speed?

Comment: Read where? Which page?

Comment: A book we use in school. However, there is no further explanation. Maybe I misunderstood. If you have better explanation.